# Perf trace shows not all tracepoints for every run

Tags: linux-kernel, perf, ebpf

I am trying to see tracepoints to track a ping packet's journey. 
First run

```
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$ sudo perf trace --no-syscalls --event 'net:*' ping 10.0.2.2 -c 1 |column
     0.705 net:net_dev_queue:dev=enp0s3 skbaddr=0xffff88003c70d200 len=98)
     0.719 net:net_dev_start_xmit:dev=enp0s3 queue_mapping=0 skbaddr=0xffff88003c70d200 vlan_tagged=0 vlan_proto=0x0000 vlan_tci=0x0000 protocol=0x0800 ip_summed=0 len=98 data_len=0 network_offset=14 transport_offset_valid=1 transport_offset=34 tx_flags=0 gso_size=0 gso_segs=0 gso_type=0)
     0.788 net:net_dev_xmit:dev=enp0s3 skbaddr=0xffff88003c70d200 len=98 rc=0)
PING 10.0.2.2 (10.0.2.2) 56(84) bytes of data.                  1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.289 ms         rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.289/0.289/0.289/0.000 ms
--- 10.0.2.2 ping statistics ---
```

On other runs of the same command it sometimes show more tracepoints.  I'd expect all runs to show the same tracepoints, but it's inconsistent whether it show more of less.

```
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$ sudo perf trace --no-syscalls --event 'net:*' ping 10.0.2.2 -c 1
PING 10.0.2.2 (10.0.2.2) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.2.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.127 ms
     1.588 net:net_dev_queue:dev=enp0s3 skbaddr=0xffff88003ba9a100 len=98)
     1.604 net:net_dev_start_xmit:dev=enp0s3 queue_mapping=0 skbaddr=0xffff88003ba9a100 vlan_tagged=0 vlan_proto=0x0000 vlan_tci=0x0000 protocol=0x0800 ip_summed=0 len
=98 data_len=0 network_offset=14 transport_offset_valid=1 transport_offset=34 tx_flags=0 gso_size=0 gso_segs=0 gso_type=0)
     1.676 net:net_dev_xmit:dev=enp0s3 skbaddr=0xffff88003ba9a100 len=98 rc=0)
     1.687 net:napi_gro_receive_entry:dev=enp0s3 napi_id=0 queue_mapping=0 skbaddr=0xffff88003ba9a100 vlan_tagged=0 vlan_proto=0x0000 vlan_tci=0x0000 protocol=0x0800 i
p_summed=0 hash=0x00000000 l4_hash=0 len=84 data_len=0 truesize=768 mac_header_valid=1 mac_header=-14 nr_frags=0 gso_size=0 gso_type=0)
     1.695 net:netif_receive_skb:dev=enp0s3 skbaddr=0xffff88003ba9a100 len=84)

     6.495 net:napi_gro_receive_entry:dev=enp0s3 napi_id=0 queue_mapping=0 skbaddr=0xffff88003ba9a600 vlan_tagged=0 vlan_proto=0x0000 vlan_tci=0x0000 protocol=0x0800 i
p_summed=0 hash=0x00000000 l4_hash=0 len=46 data_len=0 truesize=704 mac_header_valid=1 mac_header=-14 nr_frags=0 gso_size=0 gso_type=0)
     6.505 net:netif_receive_skb:--- 10.0.2.2 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.127/0.127/0.127/0.000 ms
dev=enp0s3 skbaddr=0xffff88003ba9a600 len=46)
     7.618 net:napi_gro_receive_entry:dev=enp0s3 napi_id=0 queue_mapping=0 skbaddr=0xffff88003ba9a600 vlan_tagged=0 vlan_proto=0x0000 vlan_tci=0x0000 protocol=0x0800 i
p_summed=0 hash=0x00000000 l4_hash=0 len=46 data_len=0 truesize=704 mac_header_valid=1 mac_header=-14 nr_frags=0 gso_size=0 gso_type=0)
     7.625 net:netif_receive_skb:dev=enp0s3 skbaddr=0xffff88003ba9a600 len=46)
     8.357 net:napi_gro_receive_entry:dev=enp0s3 napi_id=0 queue_mapping=0 skbaddr=0xffff88003ba9a400 vlan_tagged=0 vlan_proto=0x0000 vlan_tci=0x0000 protocol=0x0800 i
p_summed=0 hash=0x00000000 l4_hash=0 len=46 data_len=0 truesize=704 mac_header_valid=1 mac_header=-14 nr_frags=0 gso_size=0 gso_type=0)
     8.364 net:netif_receive_skb:dev=enp0s3 skbaddr=0xffff88003ba9a400 len=46)
```

I am able to run this any number of time and output will is not predictable.

Comment: The 2nd run appears to be showing *more* tracepoints.  You say it's inconsistent from run to run, so I guess that's just what happened this one time?  But anyway, your text is confusing, or else I'm missing something.

Comment: It's inconsistent. I am wondering why. I didn't get response related traces in the first run even though ping was successful.

Comment: Apparently you didn't understand my point about the wording in your question not matching the code blocks, so I fixed it for you.